# How to compute the average of a list of a special record in OCaml?

Tags: list, ocaml, average, record

Lets say we have a record which defines students:

```
type student = {
  name : string;
  age : int;
  grades : (float) list;
}
```

And safe them in a list like this:

```
let studentlist = [ {name="alex"; age=7; grades=[1.;2.;3.]} ; 
                    {name="bianca"; age=6; grades=[1.;1.;2.]} ];;
```

My aim is to compute the grade average of a special student which I choose per age, I select the student with the function `search`:

```
let search a lst = List.find( fun {age;_} -> a = age)lst
```

And compute the average with the help-functions , named `sum`, `length` and finally `avr` :

```
let rec sum lst = 
  match lst with 
  | [] -> 0.0
  | h :: t -> h +. sum t


let length lst = float_of_int (List.length lst);;

let avr lst = sum lst /. length lst;;
```

I don't know how to combine those functions to compute the average properly!

Answer (score 0):

Most of what you've done seems to work. For instance, `search` works.

```
utop # search 7 studentlist;;
- : student = {name = "alex"; age = 7; grades = [1.; 2.; 3.]}
```

If you want to access the `grades` field of that record, use `.` for record access.

```
utop # (search 7 studentlist).grades;;
- : float list = [1.; 2.; 3.]
```

Now that you have a list of `float` values, finding the sum or average of them should be easy by passing that value as an argument to the relevant function you've already defined.

*Bear in mind that when you use `List.find` in `search`, if you search for an age that is not present, you will get a `Not_found` exception that you will want to handle.*

---

As an aside, note that your `avr` function iterates over the list *twice*. Once to compute the sum, and ocne to compute the length.

It is possible to computer the sum, the length, and the average in a single pass. We can use a fold to do this. First off, we can define a basic left fold:

```
let rec foldl f init lst =
  match lst with 
  | [] -> init
  | x::xs -> foldl f (f init x) xs
```

Consider using this to compute the length of a list:

```
foldl (fun i _ -> i + 1) 0 [1.; 2.; 3.]
```

When evaluated:

```
foldl (fun i _ -> i + 1) 0 [1.; 2.; 3.]
foldl (fun i _ -> i + 1) (0 + 1) [2.; 3.]
foldl (fun i _ -> i + 1) (1 + 1) [3.]
foldl (fun i _ -> i + 1) (2 + 1) []
3
```

But we can pass a tuple of values to foldl, building up the length, sum, and average as we go.

```
utop # let (len, sum, avg) = foldl
  (fun (len, sum, avg) x -> 
     let sum  = sum +. x         in
     let len  = len + 1          in
     let flen = float_of_int len in
     (len, sum, sum /. flen))
  (0, 0., 0.)
  [1.; 2.; 3.];;
val len : int = 3
val sum : float = 6.
val avg : float = 2.
```

Comment: Why not use the built-in `List.fold_left`?

Comment: I had already implemented `foldl` as a demonstration, so might as well use it.